# How to get the official statistics of LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know LoL wiki, but I think it's not official. So how to get the official statistics (hero ,item and etc) ?

Comment: Just because it's not official doesn't mean the information is inaccurate.  Lots of people contribute to the wiki daily; don't think it's an untrustable source.

Comment: It actually is a untrustable source since lots of people contribute to this. But since you are probably not doing this for a scientific scripture you can use the wiki.

Comment: How about the official website of lol then? I think champ info and item info is all there.

Comment: Do you want to know the information about a specific champ or item or do you want to know how everybody did in a match (champ and items bought).

Comment: Asking this without even attempting to look for it on the official site is just ignorant. -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Lyrion is generally correct. You can find champion and item statistics in the [learning section](http://leagueoflegends.com/learn) of the [official website](http://leagueoflegends.com)

There you will also find Lore, Runes, Gameplay Tips, Map Information and the Summoners Code, as well as a "Guide for new Players"